# How do I prove that the summations are equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider $S1=\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{17}+\dfrac{1}{19}+\dfrac{1}{25}\cdots$

And $S2=\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\dfrac{1}{15}+\dfrac{1}{21}+\dfrac{1}{23}\cdots$

(The denominators follow a pattern, +6,+2,+6,+2.. & +2,+6,+2,+6...)

Now these two summations are the result of the squaring of the series: $$\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\cdots$$

I can prove numerically that the two summations are equal by observing that the squared value equals $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=2S1-2S2+\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$,$(\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\cdots)$

However I would like to know the correct procedure for proving the equality between the summations. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: These two series don't converge.

Comment: Yess that was my first thought too. But the result can be proved using one method, so I thought there might be another way to show the equality :)

Comment: Assignments to a sum are not the value of the sum. A divergent sum keeps a divergent sum.

Comment: The alternating sum might converge , but it is not valid to manipulate divergent sums because they have no value.

Comment: Beautifully said. Thank you I shall stop trying to prove equality between infinities :)

Answer (score 1):

If  you define $$\begin{align} 
F(x)&=x^2-x^4-x^6+x^8+x^{10}-x^{12}-x^{14}+x^{16}+\cdots\\&=\frac{x^2(1-x^2-x^4+x^6)}{1-x^8}\\&=\frac{x^2(1-x^2)}{1+x^4}\\&=\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}-1 \end{align} $$ then:

$$\int_0^1 F(x)\,dx =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{8n+3}-\frac1{8n+5}-\frac1{8n+7}+\frac1{8n+9}\right)\tag1$$

And this sum is one way to consider $S_1-S_2.$

But we can see by the middle expression that the function $F(x)$ is positive on $(0,1),$ so this sum is positive. (We could also just compute each term of the sum with a common denominator, which I believe will show each term is positive.)

We can evaluate the integral using partial fractions, by writing $$x^4+1=(x^2+x\sqrt 2+1)(x^2-x\sqrt2+1).$$

You will get a formula for the sum in $(1)$ that involves $\arctan,$ $\ln,$ and $\sqrt2.$ it might not be pretty.

Of course, the sum in $(1)$ is just one less than your sum, so if you are correct, the value is $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}-1.$ Wolfram Alpha agrees.

If we write $S$ for this sum, rather than the inaccurate $S_1-S_2,$ you'd get:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{8}=(S+1)^2=S^2+2S+1.$$

Somehow, you've asserted that $1+S^2=\frac{\pi^2}{8},$ which is not true.